# Intermediate value theorem exams question

Tags: functions

I'm trying to prepare an exam and I've found this question that I have no idea how to solve. English isn't my first language so excuse me if I don't explain myself in the best way.

Using the Intermediate value theorem show that if **f** is a function defined in the interval ($-\infty, +\infty$) such that:

1) **$f(x) = - f(-x) $** for each x

2) the $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x))$ exits (finite or infinite),

then we can say that **c** exists and it is $f(c) = 0$. Could it be c !=  $0$?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand, thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand the necessity of the second condition. Any odd function defined at $x=0$ vanishes there since if $f(-x)=-f(x),$ then when $x=0,$ we have $f(0)=-f(0),$ which happens only if $f0)=0.$

Comment: But are you asking whether there are other zeroes apart from at the origin?

Comment: $(1)$ says that the function is [odd][1] which I think on it's own (i.e. without (2)) implies that $f(0) = 0$. In fact, $(1) \implies f(0) = -f(0) \implies 2f(0) = 0 \implies f(0) = 0$.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions

Comment: In that case, consider $f(x)=x.$ It satisfies all your conditions, yet it vanishes only for $x=0.$

Comment: Your function may have other zeros. for example, $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is an odd function such that $\exists c \neq 0 and f(c) = 0$. But every odd function must *always* have $f(0)=0$.

Comment: The limit as x tends to infinity has nothing to do with the behaviour of f(x) at and around x=0.

Answer (score 0):

Prove $\exists c$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

Allawonder and I showed in the comments that (1) $\implies$ $f(0)$ will always equal $0$ and (2) does not change this answer, it just gets rid of some of the functions we consider in the question, such as $ \sin(x)$. Also, the Intermediate Value Theorem is irrelevant here I believe. So you can stop here if all you're interested in is answering the question you've been given.

From now on, I answer your irrelevant but slightly more interesting side question "Could it be $c \neq 0$ ?", to which the answer is *(obviously) yes*, there are many such functions, and I list examples of some below.

Before you look at my answers at the bottom, refresh yourself with the following rules for even and odd function, taken from https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/functions-odd-even.html under "Special properties" at the bottom of the page, and try to come up with examples on your own based on these properties/rules.

Also, to see what the graphs of functions look like, visit [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Special Properties

**Adding:**

The sum of two even functions is even

The sum of two odd functions is odd

The sum of an even and odd function is neither even nor odd (unless one function is zero).

**Multiplying:**

The product of two even functions is an even function.

The product of two odd functions is an even function.

The product of an even function and an odd function is an odd function.

$$$$
Now for my examples...
Finite limit zero:

> \begin{align} f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)} {(1 + x^2)} \end{align}

is odd since the numerator is odd and the denominator is even. There are infinitely many zeros. Note that a denominator of $x^2$ wouldn't work since then $f(x)$ would be undefined at $x=0$.

$$$$

Or if you want the limits to be non-zero but finite, you can add some constant multiple of our good friend $ \arctan(x) $. e.g.:

> \begin{align} f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)} {(1 + x^2)} + \frac{1}{100}\arctan(x) \end{align}

which works since in terms of functions, odd + odd = odd. Based on the graph on wolframalpha, it has 4 non-trivial zeros.

$$$$

Lastly, if you want $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)) = +\infty$ (and therefore $\lim_{x\to -\infty}(f(x)) = -\infty$, then:

> \begin{align} f(x)=\sin(x) + \frac{1}{50}x \end{align}

will do the job, again using the fact that odd + odd = odd. This has a few more nontrivial zeros than the previous function, based on the graph on wolframalpha. But more importantly it does have the property $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)) = +\infty$ that you want. Something like $f(x) = x\cos(x)$ *is* odd, since even x odd = odd. However it will not do the job for your question since the limit as ${x\to +\infty}$ does not exist.

Comment: Anyway, I'm under no illusions. I've likely answered a question OP didn't intend to ask. Oh well...